# Allowing users to log in to their Microsoft account.. No UWP documentation?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, onedrive

I've been all through Microsoft's website trying to find CURRENT documentation for implementing the ability for users to connect to their Microsoft account so that their information can be automatically synced with their OneDrive account. On the website they keep directing me to a page that only supports Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. There is absolutely NO documentation specific to UWP apps.

I can go on and on about the headaches I get from trying to find UP TO DATE documentation from Microsoft about their very own technologies. But maybe I'm just a little slow, so can any of you great people help direct me to SOMETHING that details what I'm looking for?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve with regards to having user information automatically synced - are you simply trying to access a user's OneDrive to store app data, or are you trying to do something else?

If you're trying to access a user's OneDrive you can find information here: dev.onedrive.com

There is also a c# SDK that you can find here: github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Have you ever used apps like Wunderlist, which is in the App Store? When you first launch it, you are asked to log into your Microsoft account (or some other account) so that all of your tasks and lists are synchronized to the cloud.This is similar to what I'm looking to do. My app uses a local SQLite database where the users notes and the such are saved. I want them to log in so that this information is synchronized to the cloud. OneDrive seems like a good place to start from there.

Comment: Oh, and it is also similar to what Microsoft does with OneNote: You log into your Microsoft account once and from then on all of your notes are saved to the cloud (OneDrive) from then on.

Comment: I've posted a reply as an answer, so the code samples are easier to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve done something similar where I use the user’s OneDrive to backup and store data (my data is stored in files as serialised objects.) I would definitely recommend getting the OneDrive SDK from Nuget – it makes life easier as you don’t have to make your own REST calls. From the SDK you can then do:

```
var oneDriveClient = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(new[] { "wl.signin", "onedrive.readwrite" })
await oneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();
```

This uses Window’s single sign on to authenticate with OneDrive – i.e. the user isn’t prompted for a username and password, it just authenticates using the Microsoft Account the user is logged into Windows as. The first time your app does this, the user will be prompted to confirm that they are happy for your app to access their OneDrive. If they confirm, they won’t see the popup again and your app will immediately authenticate.

If you want to prompt the user for a username and password – perhaps so they can use a different account if they wish – then I believe you do the same as above, but use OneDriveClientExtentions.GetClientUsingWebAuthenticationBroker() instead. I’ve never tried this, but I think it displays the logon box you are referring to.

To use the OneDrive SDK you need to register your app with OneDrive at dev.onedrive.com, and you need to associate your app with the Windows Store.

I’d recommend working your way through the Getting Started documentation found at github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp – that’s how I got my code up and running.

Comment: I can't find those methods. Deprecated maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to MS account using [OAuth2 (Live Connect)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243647.aspx). Use `WebAuthenticationBroker` to process with the oauth flow.

For OneDrive specifically, you can read more at dev.onedrive.com.

Comment: Thanks, and I just clarified what I'm looking to achieve in a reply to Roger Hartley. Maybe you can reply to that?

Comment: You can store the user info in your backend, and when user login in new device, sync the data.